# Flinch Free skill Kinsect mechanics

Tags: monster-hunter-world, monster-hunter-world-iceborne

The Flinch Free skill text for levels 1-3 now includes the following wording:

> Increases some Kinsect extract effects.

Can anyone disambiguate this with information about which effects are increased and by how much?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you create an insect glaive build with 3 points in Flinch Free, then a triple kinsect buff increases Earplugs, Tremor Resistance, and Wind Resistance by 3 points in each category. Customizing your decorations to include Flinch Free 3, Ear Plugs 2, and Wind Resistance 2 will max out Flinch Free, Ear Plugs, Wind Resistance and Tremor Resistance. Works great with Ruinous Catastrophe because slots are more available.

Flinch Free 3 and Ear Plugs 2 is typically my build to provide me with Flinch Free 3, Ear Plugs 5, Wind Resistance 3 and Tremor Resistance 3 when the kinsect is triple buffed.  Power Prolonger further adds to the build if you struggle to maintain enough uptime on the triple buff.

Answer (score 1):

Alright so I don't have much information on this personally, but this is an article I found that discusses the new skill changes:
https://gamewith.net/monsterhunterworld-iceborne/article/show/10811

Near the bottom it lists flinch free and says "When 3 extracts have been gathered by the Kinsect, knockback reduction is improved even more."

IG users gain "1 rank of flinch free" (do not really get the skill, but you do get its effects) from getting all 3 extracts together, alongside other bonuses. Based off the article, the change likely means that it increases the level of flinch free to either the 2nd level or 3rd level when you gather all 3 extracts and have 1 rank of flinch free in your armor set.
I hope the article helps a bit but I am hoping I am correct on this, if not I will see if I can post that information.